# Donwloading XLSX file from GitHub and preserve the formatting

Tags: java, excel, github

I am trying to download(from Github) an excel report with the formatting and formula intact.
But, when I convert it to a input stream, I just get binary data. How do we download an excel from Github and preserve formatting ?

Below is what I have :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;

public class DownloadDDFromGit {
    public void Download(String url) throws IOException
    {
    URL u;
    InputStream is = null;
    DataInputStream dis;
    String s;
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    u = new URL(url);
    is = u.openStream();
    dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
OutputStream out= null;
File file = new File("D:/Local.xlsx");
//OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = dis.read(buffer)) != -1 )
{

    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://git.ap.person123.com/projects/BDP/repos/atlas_script/browse/tagsAutomation/test_atlas_tags_automation.xlsx?at=refs%2Fheads%2FDEVO-108&raw";
        DownloadDDFromGit dwld = new DownloadDDFromGit();
        dwld.Download(url);

    }

}
```

Comment: I do not really understand your question. XLSX is per se binary (a zipped XML).

Comment: @D.Kovács Thanks for helping out. As you pointed out correctly, the system.out.println was mangled as I couldn't decode them, but the file being written to local directory is correct.